# i want to datepicker to clear on reset button

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

this is my component.ts

```
resetFilter() {
    this.date = 0;
    this.query.startDate= null;
    this.query.endDate=null;
    this.search = '';
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.machineId = Number(params['id']);
      this.machinesService.getItem(this.machineId).subscribe((response) => {
        this.machineDetail.MachineChanges = response.MachineChanges;
      });
    });
  }
```

this is my component.html

```
  <volante-slottrak-ui-custom-datepicker class="custom-date mb-2"  [placeholder]="'Start Date'"
            [model]="query.startDate"  (modelOutput)="onStartDateChange($event)">
          </volante-slottrak-ui-custom-datepicker>
          
          <volante-slottrak-ui-custom-datepicker  id="test"class="custom-date mb-2" [placeholder]="'End Date'"
            [model]="query.endDate" (modelOutput)="onEndDateChange($event)">
          </volante-slottrak-ui-custom-datepicker>.
          
          <button (click)="resetFilter()" class="reset-filters-btn m-r-10 mb-2" id="resetFiltersMealLog">
            <span class="reset-filters-text">Reset All</span>
          </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a service that is injected in both components and "bounce" your reset command through an observable that is declared in the service.
If the datepicker is your own component and you can modify the files:

export an Typescript interface in a d.ts file like so

```
    export interface DatePickerData{
        date: string,
        startDate: string,
        endDate: string,
        search: string 
    }
```

Then create a shared Service for both components:

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class SharedService {
    //could also be a Subject depending on your needs
    private resetRequested$:BehaviorSubject<DatePickerData> = new BehaviorSubject<DatePickerData>(null)
    }
```

Pack your reset data in the created interface and call next with it on the service observable.

And then create a subscription in your Datepicker and react to the data that is sent from the other component.

If you dont have access to the datepicker files you can try supplying all its inputs via the async pipe with fitting observables like so:

```
    [model]="(endDateObs$ | async)"
```

and then call next on those with your reset values.
Those can also live in a service which is injected into your component and referenced directly if the created variable is public.

```
    constructor(
        public service: SharedService
      ) {}
    
    [model]="(service.endDateObs$ | async)"
```